# Split date into month and year based on number of months passed in stored procedure into a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause, recursive-query

I have a stored procedure, where takes number of numbers as a parameter. I do my query with where clause like this

```
select salesrepid, month(salesdate), year(salesdate), salespercentage 
from SalesRecords
where salesdate >= DATEADD(month, -@NumberOfMonths, getdate())
```

So for example, if @NumberOFmonths passed  = 3 and based on todays date,

It should bring, september 9, october 10 and november 11  in my resultset. My query brings it but request is I need to return null for those salesrep who doesnt have a value for a month,

for example:

```
salerepid     month      year     salespercentage
 232          9         2020       80%
 232          10        2020       null
 232          11        2020       90%
```

how can I achieve this ? Right now the query brings back only two records and does not bring october data as no value is there, but i want it to return october with null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can generate all start of months within the target interval, and `cross join` that with the table to generate all possible combinations. Then you can bring the table with a `left join`:

```
with all_dates as (
    select datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) salesdate, 0 lvl
    union all
    select dateadd(month, - lvl - 1, salesdate), lvl + 1
    from all_dates 
    where lvl < @NumberOfMonths
)
select r.salesrepid, d.salesdate , s.salespercentage
from all_dates d
cross join (select distinct salesrepid from salesrecords) r
left join salesrecord s
    on  s.salesrepid = r.salesrepid
    and s.salesdate >= d.salesdate 
    and s.salesdate <  dateadd(month, 1, d.salesdate )
```

Your original query and result imply that there is at most one record per sales rep and month, so this works under the same assumption. If that's not the case (which would somehow make more sense), you would need aggregation in the outer query.

Comment: you are right there is a group by in my query by salesrepid and salesdate

Comment: @KarthikDooty: ok, so you should have a `group by  r.salesrepid, d.salesdate` in the above query - and use some kind of aggregate function on `s.salespercentage`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare @numberofmonths int = 3;

```
with all_dates as (
    select datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) dt, 0 lvl
    union all
    select dateadd(month, - lvl - 1, dt), lvl + 1
    from all_dates 
    where lvl < 3
)
select * from all_dates

This gives me following result:
2020-11-01  0
2020-10-01  1
2020-08-01  2
2020-05-01  3

I want only:
2020-11-01  0
2020-10-01  1
2020-09-01  2
```

Comment: plus its not giving me any null records also. only matching records are coming from the query, appreciate the reply